# ERROR in animate (1023: Incompatible override. AND 1021: Duplicate function definition.)

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to Adobe Animate and action script so I really dont know how to fix this.

I'm creating a mcq quiz which goes like this:
if user choose answer a or b or c or d. if a is correct answer, give 1 mark, choose wrong answer 0 mark

The source of the two errors is in the function speed.

Here is the code I made so far...

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
stop();
question.text="the question is"

var totalscore=3;
var currentscore=0;

function mark()
{
    currentscore = currentscore + 1;
}


/* Click to Go to Scene and Play
Clicking on the specified symbol instance plays the movie from the specified scene and frame.

Instructions:
1. Replace "Scene 3" with the name of the scene you would like play.
2. Replace 1 with the frame number you would like the movie to play from in the specified scene.
*/

ans1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_24);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene_24(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "quiz 2");
    currentscore = currentscore + 1;
}

ans2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_24);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene_24(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "quiz 2");
    currentscore = currentscore + 0;
}

ans3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_24);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene_24(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "quiz 2");
    currentscore = currentscore + 0;
}
ans4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_24);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene_24(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "quiz 2");
    currentscore = currentscore + 0;
}


stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 functions there all with the same name. That's probably the source of the error.

Also, your script is too complicated. You don't even need 4 different handlers to begin with.

```
// Subscribe a single handler to all 4 buttons.
ans1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onAnswer);
ans2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onAnswer);
ans3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onAnswer);
ans4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onAnswer);

function onAnswer(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Event.target contains the reference to the source of the event.
    // Figuring if that was a correct answer is easy.
    if (e.target == ans1)
    {
        currentscore += 1;
    }

    // In any case...
    (root as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay(1, "quiz 2");
}
```

Comment: thx for helping, now i face the problem which is the mark cannot keep add on and also cannot use same function because of duplicate function definition. how solve it??

````
ans1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Answer);
ans2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Answer);
ans3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Answer);
ans4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Answer);

function Answer(f:MouseEvent):void
{

    if (f.target == ans1)
    {
        currentscore += 1;
    }
 
 trace(currentscore);
 (root as MovieClip).gotoAndPlay(1, "quiz 3");
}

````

Comment: if i use same function name, it will come out error with duplicate function definition....so i try to change it. so how can i the score can keep add on without change the function?